# Why this short C code is detected as a Virus?

Tags: c, malware, virus

I just found this code is detected as a virus with some antivirus programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* func(char *str) {
    return str;
}

void main() {
    char *str = "What the hack\n";
    char *str2 = func(str);
    printf(str2);
}
```

VirusTotal scan result Image:

[image]

Do you know why??

Comment: I compiled it, no virus.  Perhaps your computer has some viruses.

Comment: Possibly because it has the word "hack" in it? In any case, I'm not *sure* it's a programming-related question??

Comment: regardless of what Visual Studio may allow, the return type from`main()` is ALWAYS `int`

Comment: this line: `printf(str2);`  does not compile, suggest: `printf( "%s\n", str2 );`

Comment: You can compile, and upload to virustotal.com

Comment: @user3629249 What? That surely compiles.

Comment: @user3629249, `printf` with a `char*` compiles fine. It may not be a good idea if you don't control the content, but you definitely *do* control it in this case.

Comment: I thought "printf" works with pointer , so it maybe works

Comment: Maybe I should have said: Does not cleanly compile.  Here is what my `gcc` compiler has to say about the `printf()` statement:  *warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]*

Comment: @paxdiablo Original string was "fxxk" I think "hack" doesn't matter

Comment: @user3629249 A warning is obviously not an error.

Comment: I get only one positive with your code _Qihoo-360 HEUR/QVM10.1.0000.Malware.Gen_

Comment: @Danh at virustotal.com ?? . What is Malware.Gen..?? Does that code generate Malware?

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/eb71a851a02063417522a7fbdb7afd2b821831f903c90737ea9fa7dc9b689568/analysis/1484629337/

Comment: I have never heard about Qihoo-360. I don't think that code generate Malware. And your malware analysis is difference from mine, I think it's your computer.

Comment: [link](https://virustotal.com/ko/file/e6c4c735777ef16780f094f9f979999dd66752dd595e235897c4cedf42e76bbb/analysis/1484629341/) why is it different between my result and your result? @Danh

Comment: I complied it with [VS 2015](https://virustotal.com/en/file/5e86796475bec9466c6c8a717ffb65301509996afed9b51fb8a220d258505db4/analysis/1484661745/) and [mingw-w64](https://virustotal.com/en/file/abd1c0f29cb0366f09335811a4d3b3f57326e1c1640382581b102f87bfa425fe/analysis/1484656874/) and did not get many of those detections. Which compiler+linker do you use?

Comment: Malware.Gen means a "generic" detection instead of a signature based. That can mean a number of things, e.g. too high entropy indicating compressed/encrypted data, an uncommon section/import/resource/... layout, a very small executable, EOF data, ...

Comment: As is easy to look for `"What the hack"` in the executable, edit that string to include a `%` and cause problems with `printf("%sat the hack");`, perhaps a prior virus used similar code?

Answer (score 0):

**The issue:**

Your program is an executable file that you compiled. That means that it doesn't have any background. Your program will raise fewer flags if, for example, it had a [verified publisher](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a674d011-6d4d-43d0-9a3b-ea8143a44716/how-do-i-change-verified-publisher-unknown-to-verified-publisher-my-name-goes-here-in-the?forum=windowssecurity) associated with it. [See this post for some more detail on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14375532/4808244) In addition, your app runs invisibly; that is, it does not allow user input. [That is often a 'red flag' that will be detected by some antivirus programs.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d1a1288-0265-407f-ad2c-fb39f893d63f/my-program-is-seen-as-a-virus?forum=vbgeneral)

**Proof:**

Your initial program looks like this when I compile it:
[image: as-is]
However, I altered the program like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* func(char *str) {
    return str;
}

void main() {
    char str[] = "What the heck\n";
    char *str2 = func(str);
    printf(str2);
}
```

the program looks like this (the word was changed to heck and initialized differently):

[image: slightly altered program]

Note that it looks *exactly* the same.

Now, when I alter the program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//char* func(char *str) {
//    return str;
//}

void main() {
    char str[] = "What the heck\n";
    //char *str2 = func(str);
    //printf(str2);
}
```

the results look like this:

[image: near-empty program]